# JPEG baseline standard VS progressive: compression cost

Tags: jpeg, image-compression

We are JPEG-compressing a large quantity of images on the fly.

This is a server-side process to interactively prepare images to be sent to the clients' browsers.

Using progressive compression would improve the user experience.

I know that this compression requires more computation for decompression, but that's not an issue.

**I'd like to know if progressive compression is more costly too and how much** (without running my own serie of tests and benchmarks).

Comment: What cost (time/size)? Progressive JPEG definitely takes more CPU time to implement; is that what you're asking or are you asking if the files will be larger?

Comment: I was talking about CPU time.

Comment: Depending on how you implement it, it doesn't have to be a drastic difference, and it depends on how many scans you create for each image. Progressive encoding will also need more temporary memory since the FDCT transformed MCUs must be kept in memory. Each scan must loop through each coefficient of each MCU and extract the correct bits, then entropy encode them. The actual quantity of memory and CPU needed for progressive encoding is unique to each codec since there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: I'm using MAC OS X's Core Graphics API to do the thing. And I'm experiencing a noticeable increase in compression time. I'll definitely run some benchmarks. However with surprise I noticed several browsers doesn't render progressive jpegs scan by scan, one is Safari (both mobile and desktop).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac, so I can't comment. It makes sense that some browsers would not display the image progressively because it would require interaction between the codec and the browser rendering engine. If the codec used is an external library, there may not be an option to receive the lower resolution images as they are decoded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After running benchmarks I noticed that **generating a JPEG requires an amount of cpu time that is roughly proportional to the number of progressive scans**

What I stated in my question...

> Using progressive compression would improve the user experience

is actually false since most browsers show the image only when completely loaded by the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compressing on the fly, then baseline will allow you to *stream* compressed data to the client even before you finish downloading and converting rest of the image. This will let you reduce latency. OTOH to compress progressive JPEG you need to download entire source image first.

For small images like thumbnails or avatars it won't matter either way.

For large images… it depends on compressor, number of progressive scans, and image sizes. Cost could be negligible compared to optimized baseline, or could be doubled compared to one-pass streaming encoder.